# Slow localhost load running Rails and Webrick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webrick

I am running Rails on in my development environment and Webrick is unbearably slow. I am not really able to find out why.

The CPU utilization bounces between 6 and 12%, and the memory utilization hovers at 18% throughout the load.

I found a website where the author recommended changing the webrick config (...\lib\ruby\2.0.0\webrick\config.rb):

```
General + {
...
      #:DoNotReverseLookup => nil, #original setting
      :DoNotReverseLookup => true,
}
```

I also rebooted my box in case something like that was the solution, but no change.

Here is the load:

[image: slow load]

What is causing this slow load and how do I fix it?

Edit: I am using a Windows 7 dev environment, 24 GB, 3.1 GHz, running postgres.

Comment: I had a problem similar to that, banging my head against the wall... Turned out it was bad JAVASCRIPT on the client, not server side... The way to debug, both server side and client side, is to add logger events (rails: logger.debug, javascript:console.log) and use current timestamp to see where time shifts for many seconds...

Comment: Where? Application.js or just all the JS files?

Comment: I wouldn't know. That's why you debug... You use gross code units and then you narrow down as you go... I'd suggest you use Chrome's developer tools, it prints debug messages as they get executed by the code. Firefox displays them after full loading.

Comment: Running a full stack like Rails on a development host, especially if you're using a database, can drain a machine's CPU and I/O throughput. You don't say what your system, hardware, CPU, RAM and disk speeds are so we can't really guess whether your system is being pushed beyond its limits. I've experienced similar problems, and ended up having to spin off my database and HTTP to a separate machine, which easily doubled the speed of the overall system, even as an untuned development system.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but I would recommend using [puma](http://puma.io) or [thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) instead of webrick. They provide better performance overall, and aren't any heavier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WEBrick is doing a reverse DNS lookup on connecting IPs by default. In other words, it's trying to see if your IP address is associated with a domain name. This is unnecessary and takes too long, so you can disable it.

Open the file `"l/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/config.rb"` and locate the line with `":DoNotReverseLookup => nil"`.
Change `nil` to `true`.

Enjoy!